# order of features & step definitions/specs in ruby apps? (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber, bdd

I am new to rails, cucumber and rspec. To help learn all three, I've started building a realistic application that requires login.

I would appreciate a little guidance as to where to start and confirmation I am on the right path.

I started with 2 features files.  However, I have stopped at this stage as I'm wondering whether the 'login' feature (although a core aspect of the app as they can't do anything without being logged in) should come after the other assets and models, such as the things they manage when they are logged in.

So, which would come first? Features for the login or features for the models they manage?

example feature files:

```
Feature: User loads application

  As a user
  I want be able to load the application
  So that I can manage my files

  Scenario: Load application
    Given I am not yet using the application
    When I visit the application
    Then I should see "Welcome to app"
```

login feature file:

```
Feature: User logs in

  As a user
  I want be able to login
  So that I can manage my private files

  Scenario: Successful login
    Given the user "Username" has an account
    When they login
    Then they should see "You have logged in successfully"
```

Should I have started with a feature that they will actually use as the point of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which you implement features is a *business decision*. Whether you start with the login process or another feature depends on the business value each feature carries.

To help you find out where to start, you'll need to ask questions to the stakeholders. Here are a few examples:

- *Could we build feature A without user authentication?*
- *Do we absolutely need user authentication at this point?*
- *Let's consider we have resources to build only one single feature, what would be the most valuable one right now: login or feature A?*

Building *feature A* before authentication *can* be a good strategy, as you'll be able to expose the feature to test users and improve on it earlier. Or, it could make no sense at all on your specific project and you'd want authentication to be ready before anything else.

Now, to comment on your particular scenarios, the style your using is pretty good.

I have the feeling (I might be wron) the *user loads application* feature is not really useful though. As a user, do you care about a "welcome to app" message? This scenario looks like a pre-functional setup test, something you'd like to have as a developer to kick off the development process. But it does not seem (again I might be wrong) to tell anything useful about the behaviour of the application.

This could be encapsulated behind a Cucumber feature describing some **real** expected behaviour of your systm (like the login process or adding items to a cart or reading blog posts, whatever is relevant to your domain).